# Images Files in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, imageurl

How to redirect image attachment URL's to parent post or picture file in Drupal 7?
For example: 
https://www.mysite/file/298 to https://mysite.pl/sites/default/files/dsc_298.jpg

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: In Yoast for Wordpress there is an option - Redirect attachment URLs to parent post URL. I would like to do that for Drupal.